# ng-hide showing up shortly when loading page

Tags: angularjs

I have a div that is usually hidden:

```
<div id="errorDiv" x-ng-show="errorOccured">
    {{errorStatus}}: {{errorMessage}}
</div>
```

when I load the page, I see it for a short second, which I don't want.
So I tried hiding it at start:

```
<div id="errorDiv" x-ng-show="errorOccured" class="ng-hide">
    {{errorStatus}}: {{errorMessage}}
</div>
```

but that didn't work :-(
Is there any good way to hide a div at the time of page loading?

Comment: it turns out my solution would have worked. The problem was angularjs being loaded at bottom of page. But I guess ng-cloak is the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ng-cloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I also had to add ng-cloak css to my css file, since I load angularjs at bottom of page. Is that bad practice?

Comment: I have noticed that there are some times where i still encounter brief view flashes even with ng-cloak, a better solution is to use the one way binding of ng-bind (and ngbindTemplate mentioned below) where ever possible.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher: Putting scripts at the end of your page is useful if you want to render the page before loading scripts - in this case, however, that may not be what you want. Defining .ng-cloak in your own styles may be bad in case they're implemented in a different way in future. You could add your own class which is removed once the DOM (and angular) has loaded.

Comment: @JaredReeves: If you load angular.js at the bottom of the page, this is how it will manifest. ngBindTemplate may be fine for most cases but for non-trivial templates it makes your views a lot harder to read and maintain.

Comment: @JussiKosunen: I understand that view flashes are largely the result of loading angular at the bottom, however I have encountered this when angular is loaded at the top of the page as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `ngCloak`, there's always `ngBindTempalate`. Then your html would look like this:

```
<div id="errorDiv" ng-show="errorOccured" ng-bind-template="{{errorStatus}} : {{errorMessage}}"></div>
```

Documentation here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate

It won't hide the div, but it won't populate it with ugly curly braces either.